# How to query/call @JoinTable annotation of hibernate from java

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, java-8

I have created two tables: Project and Resource. There entity class are as follows:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="project")
public class Project {

    @Id
    private int projectId;
    private String name;
    private String createdBy;
    .
    .
    .
}

@Entity
@Table(name="resource")
public class Resource {

    @Id
    private int resourceId;
    private String name;
    private String createdBy;
    private Set<Project> projects;

    @JoinTable(name="project_resources",joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="project_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="resource_id")})
    public Set<Project> getProjects() {
        return projects;
    }

    public void setProjects(Set<Project> projects) {
        this.projects = projects;
    }

    .
    .
}
```

some database values:

```
resource_id, project_id
r-123-abcop, p-qweer033
r-153-adetr, p-qweer033
r-460-uerty, p-qweer033
r-087-xcvbx, p-qweer033
r-askf-44uj, p-euyru85r
r-6yhe-hefn, p-euyru85r
r-er7u-ufgm, p-euyru85r
r-ehw8i-nfm, p-euyru85r
```

(There is no entity class for table project_resources, Project table will not have the Resource table dependency, but Resource will have Project's as you can see from classes)

Now, if want to get which resources are present in project, then i have to first get all the resources then filter resource based on project id. But if i am able to query this project_resources table i will able to get those value easily.

I want to generate query something like

```
select * from project_resources where project_id = '';
```

How to make hibernate class understand to pick this project_resources table? Or any better solution how to get resources based on projectId?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need create table `project_resources`.With JPA mapping many to many, you can using query in `project` class. it will be auto mapping to resource. You can refer link https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many

Comment: Okay. But in my Project entity i don't have dependency of Resource entity. So i think ManyToMany will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this named query

```
@NamedQuery(
            name = "getResourcesByProjectid",
            query =select r from Resource r left join r.projects p where p.projectId = ?1
)
```